# Field added to schema but not reflecting in tridion

Tags: web8.5, web8

I have added "VideoLinkurl" field to the existing Page Hero schema in DXA application and deployed. But the field is not showing up in tridion. Ours is a Web 8.5 set up. Am i missing any step?

[SemanticProperty("BgVideoLinkUrl")]
public string BgVideoLinkUrl { get; set; }

Comment: Did you add the field to the schema in the Tridion CME or did you just add that property to the model class in DXA?

Comment: In the model in the DXA code solution (backend content API solution)

Comment: You need to modify the Tridion schema as well.

Comment: Did you republish the system settings page also. I always forget that!!!

Comment: Thank you for the responses. It worked after removing existing column earlier added from Tridion schema, updating new schema, re-publishing system settings the column appeared in json from backend. Thanks a lot for the direction